# Adding buttons to an expandable div (javaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I have this  HTML code

```
    <div class="canvas">
<p class ="ident"> #215625</p>
<a class="expand">   <p class="movetext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne omnis scaevola recteque nam, quas delenit te mea. Mea dico etiam cu. Commodo regione invenire ea nam, pri quidam omnium civibus ut, his ne tollit melius consectetuer. Summo affert nam eu, adolescens delicatissimi eos ei.
Sea in errem nusquam, ornatus suscipiantur ne sed. Veniam suscipit efficiendi nam id. Dolor populo fastidii mel in, te vis nusquam interpretaris. Eirmod nonumes mea ea.</p>> <a class="btn">Button Action 1</a> <a class="btn">Button Action 2</a>
</a>   
<div class="detail">
<div class = "commentCanvas">
<div><p class ="marginize">Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat.</p></center></div>
<div class="commentAuthorCanvas">
<p class="marginize"> Stojan Stojko Stojkovic</p></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And this javaScript code:

```
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$(function() {
$(".expand").on( "click", function() {
$(this).next().slideToggle(100);
$expand = $(".marginize").find(">:first-child");
});
});
</script>
```

What I want is to make the first div expandable. The thing is that it is not showing other div's content when I add buttons.
Can anyone help me out? I am not that good with javascript, but I need this done as soon as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: this is a jsfiddle with your code http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/2ourc71j/ .. update this with related code .. to let us know what do you want exactly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2ourc71j/2/
Here, I updated it. I added the css, so it may lead you to some point.
Basically, I want that when you click on the first div content (not the buttons) to expand the div and show the comment seciton and the commentAuthor section

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/2ourc71j/3/ is this what you want?

Comment: you welcome ... Good Luck :) .. let me add it as a answer to be a reference to anyone else have a same issue

Comment: Can you help me, how can I mark it answered, I am a little lost :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **.closest()** and **.find()**

```
$(".expand").on( "click", function() {
    $(this).closest('.canvas').find('.detail').slideToggle(100);
    //$expand = $(".marginize").find(">:first-child");
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/2ourc71j/4/)